# How to change height of UITableView from code when using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a page inside which I must have 2 `UITableView`s using *Autolayout*. They will be taken about half of the screen each. My problem is that the logic of the page requires one of them to be hidden from time to time. In that case I need to expand the other to occupy the whole screen.

My logic is:

On the open of the page I will see only 1st  `UITableView` with a list inside. When I click on a row I will have to show the the second `UITableView` bellow the first, so the will split the screen by 50-50 (it would be better to calculate proper height of the second one, but 50-50 is ok).

After making some operations inside the second it will be set hidden and the first must be expanded to entire screen again.

My question is how to do that?

I suppose that I must add height constraints, but I have to remove and add them dynamically or I have to do something else?

P.S. I suppose that when I show both if the content of the first is larger that visible area it will support scrolling?

*View before selection (only one `UITableView`):*

```
---------------------
| * Row 1           |
| * Row 2           |
| * Row 3           |
| * Row 4           |
| * Row 5           |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------
```

*View before selection (both `UITableView` are visible):*

```
---------------------
| * Row 1           |
| * Row 2           |
| * Row 3 (SELECTED)|
---------------------
| x row 1           |
| x row 2           |
| x row 3           |
| x row 4           |
---------------------
```

Comment: You can add property of TableView's height constraint and change it when you want this way: `_constraintTableViewHeight.constant = 440.`;

Comment: Cool idea (at least I did not figure out myself :) ). I suppose that I have to subclass those `UITableViews`, 10x @Vladislav Kovalyov.

Comment: It depends on your realisation. It can be enough to add this property to your controller class. Int his case you don't have to subclass TableViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:
- Add height constraints for the Tableviews
- Declare two `NSLayoutConstraint` properties in the `ViewController` defined as `IBOutlet`
- Connect the variables to the constraints in Interface Builder.
Then in your ViewController you can adjust the heights of the TableViews modifying the constant of the NSLayoutConstraint property. E.g.

```
self.heightOfTheFirstTableView.constant = self.view.frame.size.height/2;
self.heightOfTheSecondTableView.constant = self.view.frame.size.height/2;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

And for your question:

> P.S. I suppose that when I show both if the content of the first is
>   larger that visible area it will support scrolling?

Yes it will support scrolling but only if the user scrolls inside the tableView frame